# View.stopListening() not working

Tags: backbone.js

http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/3KAhC/

In this fiddle code the even though the stopListening method is called the on method is still in effect as can be seen by the output. What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
// Define View
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // Listen to the model
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        $("#message").append("<br>render called");
    },

    close: function () {
        this.stopListening();
    }
});

var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var someModel = new SomeModel({
    name: 'Foo'
});
var someView = new SomeView({
    model: someModel
});

someModel.set('name', 'Bar');
someView.close();
someView = null;
someModel.set('name', 'Zoo');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)` instead of `this.model.on('change', this.render, this)`:

> **[listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)** object.listenTo(other, event, callback)
>   Tell an object to
>   listen to a particular event on an other object. The advantage of
>   using this form, instead of `other.on(event, callback)`, is that
>   `listenTo` allows the object to keep track of the events, and they can
>   be removed all at once later on.

And an updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/3KAhC/1/